# Single quote replace with double quotes

Tags: bash

I have a parameter and I passed the vale `'123'`,`'234'`,`'456'`.

```
$p='123','234','456'
```

I want to display this value in 2 different places.

- 1 place I will use above parameter=`'123'`,`'234'`,`'456'`
- 2 place also I will use same `$p` parameter and my output should display like below.

```
''123'',''234'',''456''
```

How can i achieve this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set two variables...

Comment: No.. i want to do it 1 variable..Hence in two places i am going to use same parameter $p

Comment: You can't have a variable with two different values. You will either have to use two or set it with the different value before you use it the second time?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you will have to make sure that the single quotes are actually part of the variable's value:

```
p="'123','234','456'"
```

The double quotes around the string `'123','234','456'` prevents the shell from removing the single quotes.  Without the double quotes, the variable's value would have been set to the string `123,234,456`.  Note also that to assign a value to the variable `p`, no `$` should precede the variable's name.

Now you can output your variable's value with the single quotes like so:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$p"
'123','234','456'
```

You can also output it with the single quotes changed into double single quotes like so:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${p//\'/\'\'}"
''123'',''234'',''456''
```

Or double quotes (this was what I thought you wanted before the markup of your question was corrected):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${p//\'/\"}"
"123","234","456"
```

The `${p//\'/\'\'}` and `${p//\'/\"}'` bits are examples of  parameter substitutions that changes all single quotes into double single quotes or double quotes (respectively) in the value `$p`.  The general form of that substitution looks like `${variable//pattern/string}`.

---

When you have a list of separate things, such as the numbers 123, 234, and 456, the best way to store them is in an array:

```bash
p=( 123 234 456 1,234 "6'15\"" )   # Added 1,234 an 6'15" as extra elements
```

This avoids any ambiguity regarding what constitutes an element, especially if an element could include things like commas or quotes (as in `1,234` or `6'15"`) or whatever other characters you later want to add between each pair of elements.  The typical case is maybe not positive integers, but if you find yourself dealing with *pathnames*, these could potentially contain *any* character apart from nul (`\0`) and telling one pathname apart from another when they are stored in a single string could be difficult.

You could then generalise your issue into one that involves modifying each element of that array by adding a string as prefix and suffix.  A solution to such a generalised problem could be carried out by a shell function:

```bash
add_flanking_string_to_each () {
    # Adds a string to each element in an array,
    # both before each and after each element.
    # Requires bash 4.3+ for using name references.

    # Arg 1: name of input array
    # Arg 2: name of output array (will be emptied)
    # Arg 3: string

    local -n inarray="$1"
    local -n outarray="$2"
    local string="$3"

    local element

    outarray=()
    for element in "${inarray[@]}"; do
        outarray+=( "$string$element$string" )
    done
}
```

You then call this helper function to create the data that you want to have:

```bash
for string in "'" "''" '"'; do
    add_flanking_string_to_each p pnew "$string"

   ( IFS=','; printf '%s\n' "${pnew[*]}" )
done
```

This would output

```
'123','234','456','1,234','6'15"'
''123'',''234'',''456'',''1,234'',''6'15"''
"123","234","456","1,234","6'15""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "${p//\'/\'\'}"
''123'',''234'',''456''
```

to get exactly what you asked for.